# generate pdf bundle

Tags: symfony

I'm using the bundle psliwa pdfbundle and generates pdfs successfully but I do not know how to save the pdf on the server and be able to put in the mysql database the path to that generated pdf.

someone help me? use Symfony2 thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation https://github.com/psliwa/PHPPdf#parsing you will find how to render ad output the PDF to the user.

This is done by

```
//$documentXml and $stylesheetXml are strings contains XML documents, $stylesheetXml is optional
$content = $facade->render($documentXml, $stylesheetXml);

header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
echo $content;
```

If you want to save the PDF as a file on the filesystem you just have to do

```
//$documentXml and $stylesheetXml are strings contains XML documents, $stylesheetXml is optional
$content = $facade->render($documentXml, $stylesheetXml);
$filename = '/path/to/the/file.pdf';
file_put_contents($filename, $content);
```

You can find the documentation for the function *file_get_contents* at http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

But your question does not have something to do with the bundle itself. It's a general question about how to save files in PHP and how to do that could easily found with a search engine like [Google](http://www.google.de)